# What are turnaround times like in Finance, Financial Economics, Economics / Econometrics journals?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, paper-submission, economics

What are turnaround times like in Finance, Financial Economics, Economics / Econometrics journals?

I would be among at least a 1000 other aspirants looking to publish in quality journals. There seems to be no feedback/survey about how long the review process takes and what to expect as feedback for journals in this/these fields

Comment: Here is a wiki where people report Econ journal turnaround times: https://www.econjobrumors.com/journals.php

Comment: The individual journals also publish their stats. Here are Econometrica stats: http://www.econometricsociety.org/sites/default/files/reports/Report%20of%20Editors%202014-2015.pdf